# How to Make Android Tablet Apps

Tags: android

How to start developing android tablet apps ? 
what to download to develop the applications ?
 If someone could give me a simple and easy explanation of how to get started it would be very helpful. I have tried using the Android Developers site for help but it says not more about tablet apps. So if someone could just find or explain how to make android tablet apps it would be very helpful!

Thanks

Comment: You need to download the Android SDK and work through the tutorials.

Comment: Hi Chris I think u got the answer by the time. Harper and Brain give u good idea about app development, please accept answers that seems done the work for you .. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I know I am linking you back to the android dev site but it is the best. I will throw in some more links at the bottom (although not as great). Keep in mind that tablets mostly run a higher version of android than phones. (3.1(tablet), vs. 2.2(phone))

If you have not seen this page then this will help you. It takes you step by step through installing all your resources and then writing hello world.

Step one: Prepare your dev environment wit the SDK, Eclipse, etc etc

[Install SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Step two: Write Hello World

[Hello World](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

Additional Links

[Starting Tuorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial)

[Android-er Blog Tutorials](http://android-er.blogspot.com/) - These are updated daily and the list is on the right side.

Comment: Well my probelm is that i have downloaded the SDK and JDK and don't understand how to get from the SDK manager to actually making a app?

Comment: If you have the SDK, IDE and everything installed properly you can follow the Hello World tutorial. If that doesn't work something is not installed/loaded right from step one.

Comment: @ Chris Bacon Make sure the components are installed and when starting a project you should have the option create new android project.

Comment: I have realised that i need 'Eclipse' to start making apps, correct? As i don't have this installed at the moment.

Comment: @Chris Bacon Eclipse is the recommended IDE, yes you will need that in order to write apps. Do each step in the first link and you should be fine. Some things can cause trouble but the tutorial lists alternates.

Comment: Now a new problem, just gone to go and download 'Eclipse' and when the download link is click it downloads a 5.5kb php file?

Comment: From my link click the eclipse downlaod link then do classic for your bit type machine, and you should get an install .exe

Comment: Now downloading, thank you all, will let you know how i get on once everything is downloaded and started running

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go through the Android SDK first. There is no different between developing a phone or pad android application except the UI design part.

So go through the SDK first and post the specific problem while developing.